Automatic pull request in Azure Devops
Is it possible in Azure Devops to automatically create a pull request to a development branch when pushing to a feature branch?
I tried searching any option that is ready in Azure Devops but cant seem to find anything usefull. So I think it has to be something external but I haven't seen any good free options yet.

You can use the Azure DevOps REST API "Pull Requests - Get Pull Requests" to check if there is an active PR for merging changes from feature to development branch.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository}/pullrequests?searchCriteria.sourceRefName=refs/heads/feature&searchCriteria.targetRefName=refs/heads/development&searchCriteria.status=active&api-version=7.1

Replace {organization}, {project} and {repository} with the actual names of your Azure DevOps organization, project and git repository. Same in subsequent steps.
If no such active PR exists, call the API "Pull Requests - Create" to create a new PR for merging changes from feature to development branch.
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository}/pullrequests?api-version=7.1

{
  "sourceRefName": "refs/heads/feature",
  "targetRefName": "refs/heads/development",
  "title": "Merge changes",
  "description": "Merge some changes from refs/heads/feature to refs/heads/development.",
  "isDraft": false
}


To let above API can be automatically called when has new changes pushed to feature branch, you can configure a pipeline like following the steps below:

Go to "Project Settings" > "Service connections" to create a Generic service connection.

Server URL: https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project} is the common prefix of the API URI mentioned above.
Service connection name: A custom name of the service connection.



Go to "Project Settings" > "Repositories" > (select a particular repository if you want to set security only for it) > "Security". Ensure the following permissions are 'Allow' for the identities "Project Collection Build Service ({Organization-Name})" and "{Project-Name} Build Service ({Organization-Name})".

Read
Contribute
Contribute to pull requests



Create a YAML pipeline with the configurations like as below. Ensure the YAML file auto-create-pr.yml exists on the feature branch.
# auto-create-pr.yml

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - feature

jobs:
- job: createPR
  pool: server
  steps:
  - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
    displayName: 'Check Active PR'
    inputs:
      connectionType: connectedServiceName
      serviceConnection: 'ForGitAPI'
      method: 'GET'
      headers: |
        { 
          "Authorization": "Bearer $(system.AccessToken)"
        }
      urlSuffix: '/_apis/git/repositories/{repository}/pullrequests?searchCriteria.sourceRefName=refs/heads/feature&searchCriteria.targetRefName=refs/heads/development&searchCriteria.status=active&api-version=7.1'
      successCriteria: 'ge(root[''count''], 1)'

  - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
    displayName: 'Create PR'
    condition: failed()
    inputs:
      connectionType: connectedServiceName
      serviceConnection: 'ForGitAPI'
      method: 'POST'
      headers: |
        {
          "Content-Type":"application/json", 
          "Authorization": "Bearer $(system.AccessToken)"
        }
      body: |
        {
          "sourceRefName": "refs/heads/feature",
          "targetRefName": "refs/heads/development",
          "title": "Merge changes",
          "description": "Merge some changes from refs/heads/feature to refs/heads/development.",
          "isDraft": false
        }
      urlSuffix: '/_apis/git/repositories/{repository}/pullrequests?api-version=7.1'



With above configurations, when new changes pushed to feature branch, the pipeline is automatically triggered.

The step 'Check Active PR' calls the API "Pull Requests - Get Pull Requests" to check if there is an active PR for merging changes from feature to development branch. If not exists, this step gets failed. Otherwise succeed.

If step 'Check Active PR' is failed, execute the step 'Create PR' to call the API "Pull Requests - Create" to create a PR for merging changes from feature to development branch. Otherwise skipped.




Have you tried the shared sample that uses the API "Pull Requests - Get Pull Requests" and "Pull Requests - Create"? Does it work for you? @Leand
